# JAVA - Using httpclient to post a file to google apps via http proxy (squid) gets stuck when calling execute

Tags: java, google-app-engine, proxy, httpclient

## Context

I have a desktop JAVA application I use to upload files (blobs) to a google app blobstore.
Everything works fine with a direct connection to the Internet but it doesn't when connecting through an HTTP proxy (Squid) with authentication.

I am using httpClient 4.2.3 and I don't get any error or response. It just gets stuck when calling `httpClient.execute(post)`.

## Code

I added these lines to handle the proxy authentication and it works well when using URL to get a page:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", username);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", password);
```

I tried those as well:

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(
       new Authenticator() {
           @Override
          public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(
                   username, password.toCharArray());
          }
       }
    );
```

And from now on this is the same code that works when not using a proxy.

First of all I download a page where I get the url to use to post a file to the blobstore:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/get-upload-url.jsp");        
    String urlWhereToPost=IOUtils.toString(url.openStream());  
    
    DefaultHttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient ();
```

Here we prepare the multipart post:

```
    HttpPost post
             = new HttpPost( urlWhereToPost.trim() );
    MultipartEntity entity 
             = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    entity.addPart( "key" 
                    , new FileBody(new File(jpgFilePath)
                    , "image/jpeg" )
                    );

    post.setEntity((HttpEntity)entity);
```

And it is when calling execute that nothing happens (and it never get's to the next instruction):

```
    HttpResponse execute = client.execute( post );
```

## Tests

I have been trying several things but nothing worked:

- In the beginning I thought the problem was using POST because GET works fine using `URL()`
  but I tried using `HttpClient` to execute a GET and it gets stuck as well.
- I used Wireshark to check the packets send to the proxy and I saw that when using `URL()` Wireshark recognizes the calls to the proxy as requests to execute a GET from the proxy. But when using httpClient it looks like the request is not well built because Wireshark shows a packet but doesn't recognize the inner request.
- Then I tried building the POST using `HttpURLConnection` and it gets through the proxy and I get the answer from the server but it looks like I am not building it well because appengine doesn't find the file I send (but this would be another question...).

## Conclusion

Anyone with the same problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy settings are for the Java system classes. Apache HttpClient is supposed to be configured in a different way.
This link may help: [Proxy authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java)

Comment: Right, I had tried this configuration as well and I tried again with the code you linked but the result is the same, it gets stuck when calling

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget);